# How can I check whether data has an equal number of observations per group?

Tags: r

I'm writing some code where I need to check whether all group sizes for a given input of data are equal. For example, suppose I wanted to know whether the "mpg" dataset (in the ggplot2 package) has:

- Equal numbers of cars for every manufacturer
- Equal numbers of cars for each type of drive (4-wheel, front-wheel, rear-wheel)
- Equal numbers of cars for each engine type (4-cylinder, 6-cylinder, 8-cylinder)

For data like mpg, some of those questions can be answered by inspecting the summary output

```
library(ggplot2)   # contains the mpg dataset
summary(mpg$drive) # shows the breakdown of cars by drive-type, 
                   # which we can verify is unequal
```

But I feel like I'm missing an easy way to check whether group sizes are equal. Is there some single, mythical function I can call like `are.groups.of.equal.size(x)`? Or another base function (or composition of them) that would return such information?

Comment: `table`? `aggregate`? `ddply`? Soooooo many ways to do that.

Comment: @joran - I'm trying to automate it so the solution would basically return a boolean as to whether the group sizes are equal or not. How might I use `table`, `aggregate`, or `ddply` to accomplish that?

Comment: table() returns a vector.  Just check whether all elements of that vector are equal.  sd() would be one quick way to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Joran said we could invent 100s of ways from here till Christmas on how to do this one.  I smell a microbenchmark challenge:

```
are.groups.of.equal.size <- function(x) {
    y <- rle(as.character(sort(x)))$lengths
    all(y%in%mean(y))
}


are.groups.of.equal.size(c(3, 3, 3))
are.groups.of.equal.size(mtcars$cyl)
are.groups.of.equal.size(CO2$Plant)
are.groups.of.equal.size(mtcars$carb)
```

Comment: I think `rle` was the missing piece I was looking for. What's a microbenchmark challenge?

Comment: Just see who could come up with the fastest way to do this problem since there's at least 10 i can think of off the top of my head.  The sd sugegstion was creative too that I hadn't thought of.

Answer (score 4):

Here is one way of doing it:

```
are.groups.of.equal.size <- function(x)length(unique(table(x))) == 1L

are.groups.of.equal.size(mpg$manufacturer)
# [1] FALSE
are.groups.of.equal.size(mpg$drv)
# [1] FALSE
are.groups.of.equal.size(mpg$year)
# [1] TRUE
```

Note that if needed, `table` has options for how to handle `NA`s in your data.

Answer (score 0):

Using the sd approach:

```
are.groups.of.equal.size <- function(x) {
   x2 <- tapply(x, x, length)
   sd(x2)==0 | length(x2)==1
}

are.groups.of.equal.size(c(3, 3, 3))
are.groups.of.equal.size(mtcars$cyl)
are.groups.of.equal.size(CO2$Plant)
are.groups.of.equal.size(mtcars$carb)
```